# Why are these digits appearing at different baselines?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I have several TLF objects whose text I set dynamically, and the size and baseline is appearing incorrectly for certain digits. Has anyone encountered something like this before?

You can see the difference in the 6 and 3 here. (6 is the way it's supposed to look)
[image]
[image]

And the 7s in the above number are also wrong:

[image]

The font is Helvetica Neue, Bold.

The code does not touch the text objects except when changing the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestions for this.

1. Make sure that your font is embedded for this text field (click on text field embed all numbers).
2. Double and triple check that the text field is on whole pixels eg 29, 31 (not fractions of a pixel). Check that the parent movie clip of the text field is also on whole pixels until you make it all the way back to the stage.
3. Failing that maybe re-install the font?

I have been doing actionscript for years and have never seen this, so its possible issues with the font?

Comment: I agree with John, its probably a bad font.  Here is a Helvetica Neue Bold that I regularly use for projects that you can try to see if its the font causing your trouble.  Please let me know when you have tested so I can kill the link.  Thanks!  http://www.codingfiend.com/downloads/helvetica/Helvetica_Neue_Bold.zip

Comment: Embedding the font fixed it! -Ribs, thanks for the font, but it didn't help. Neither did setting the object coordinates to integers. Curiously, I also changed the font type to classic dynamic text, and that caused the "bad" digits to be left out, i.e. instead of "6772" it would display "62". For the record, the bad digits seemed to be 0, 3, and 7.